# How to use bolt protocol to access my Neo4j Database?

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and am reading this example:

```
try ( HelloWorldExample greeter = new HelloWorldExample( "bolt://localhost:7687", "neo4j", "test" ) )
        {
            greeter.printGreeting( "hello, world" );
        }
```

In my Eclipse, this code works fine. However, I already have a Neo4j database which I can access through

```
http://localhost:7474/browser/
```

My question is in my Java code above, how can I access my existing Neo4j database? If I change "bolt://localhost:7687" to "http://localhost:7474", I received this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unsupported URI scheme: http
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:125)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory.newInstance(DriverFactory.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase.driver(GraphDatabase.java:136)
    at org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase.driver(GraphDatabase.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase.driver(GraphDatabase.java:94)
    at neo4j.Neo4j.<init>(Neo4j.java:19)
    at neo4j.Neo4j.main(Neo4j.java:50)
```

So how can I access my existing database (http://localhost:7474) through 'bolt'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a Neo4j database through 2 protocols :

- HTTP/REST on default port `7474`
- BOLT on default port `7687`

So on your example, you are trying to use a BOLT client on the HTTP, this can't work.

So the good url is the one into your java code : `"bolt://localhost:7687"`

Comment: yes that's true. But my question is regarding how to use bolt protocol to access my existing database. For example, my existing database can be browsed through http://192.168.194.3:7474/browser/, which is on another computer. bolt://192.168.194.3:7687 doesn't work.

Comment: By default Neo4j just listen on local, and not on the network. You have to uncomment this line in the `neo4j.conf` file : `dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0`

Comment: That's great to know.